# .net core docker image with app settings per customer

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have a .NET Core 2.0 web api that is running on a Docker container behind a load balancer (also a docker container). I want to scale the web api by having multiple containers, one per customer. Having that in mind I had to make changes in the configuration to separate and abstract the customer details so I can have app settings per customer. That way I would have `appsettings.CustomerA.config`, `appsettings.CustomerB.config` etc.

My general Dockerfile is:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS builder
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./Project/*.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY ./Project ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/out ./
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

That's all fine but what I don't know is whether I can have different Dockerfiles, one per customer where I specify the customer (not sure if that's a good practice or not because I would be mixing environments with customer but at the same time, the environment is for a given customer if that makes sense) or whether I should create a different config file that I copy across depending on the customer?

I took the docker template from the Microsoft docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application and added the environment myself.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to have a separate Dockerfile for each customer or even a separate image. This will quickly lead to big number of dockerfiles to manage and will introduce many complexities, especially when you want to upgrade all files/images when a new features demands so.

It is preferable to have one Docker image and externalize all customer specific configuration to the outside of the image.

There are multiple ways you can do that. In Docker, you can pass environment variables to the container to configure it. You can also wrap the environment vars in a config file and pass it as an env file.

Another "Docker way", to externalize stuff outside of the image is to use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/b). You can bind a directory from the host onto the container when running the container. In the directory, you can have config files ... that the container can pick up when starting up.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I will then configure the container to use mounts. Seems the most sensitive way to achieve what I want. I wonder how this can be automatized if I want to use a swarm. The plan is to get deployed containers on worker nodes but if choose to use mounts I would need to deploy separately the customer config to the relevant nodes. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is true. You need to have config on each machine. You can mitigate this issue by having some network sharing such as NFS. Alternatively, you can switch to something distributed such as FTP or a key value store such as Redis where each container requests its configuration based on environment variables.

Comment: I see, that's a good solution too. Many thanks for your help!